# Java Concurrent HashMap

Tags: java

i want to convert a ConcurrentHashMap to a TreeMap.Can i do that?

Comment: I'm curious as to why. If this is for performance reasons (I might be out of date, but I believe there was at one time some performance overhead with the Concurrent collections), have you profiled to make sure that this is your bottleneck?

Comment: You'll have to more specific.  A ConcurrentHashMap is a threadsafe unordered map implementation.  A TreeMap is a non-threadsafe ordered map implementation.  Show a code snippet to illustrate what you mean by "convert".

Comment: Please expand your question: Is this a one time conversion in order to access the contents in order one time, or a global code change to get sorted access multiple times?

Answer (score 6):

If you need a Sorted ConcurrentMap look at [ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html).  Considering its complexity it is both non blocking and fast.  To be more specific:

> This class implements a concurrent
>   variant of [SkipLists](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/)
>   providing   expected average
>   *log(n)* time cost for the
>   containsKey, get,
>   put and   remove
>   operations and their variants.

Answer (score 5):

A `ConcurrentHashMap` is still a `Map`. So you can create a new `TreeMap` like this:

```
ConcurrentHashMap myMap;
...
TreeMap myTreeMap = new TreeMap( myMap );
```

Comment: +1. Worth mentioning that the constructor runs in `n log(n)` time

Answer (score 2):

First I would like to point you. you should learn to read the java SDK [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/).

Like Tangens said, and the [TreeMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) API:

```
ConcurrentHashMAp myMap;
new TreeMap(myMap);
```

> "**Note that this implementation is
>   not synchronized**. If multiple threads
>   access a map concurrently, and at
>   least one of the threads modifies the
>   map structurally, it must be
>   synchronized externally"

```
SortedMap m = Collections.synchronizedSortedMap(new TreeMap(...));
```